add icon into select tag and add action to this icon
I´m traying to do a "preview action" in my component vuejs 3.
To do this, i´m trying with:
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option @click='prueba($event)' data-content="<i class='fa fa-eye mr-5' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option1"></option>
</select>

this generate:

But i want that when i clicked in eye, open modal with information contract to select this contract or other... My problem it´s that @click not run, not go to function "prueba" and show a console.log()
i don´t know if exist one way better to build this, i´m working with bootstrap 4 and vuejs 3. I think that my best way it´s a link into select andthis link open modal with information contract. But if anybody have other better solution i´m earding it.
Thanks for readme and hekp me

Try to attach the event to the select element instead of option.

click events do not work on option. please try to add onChange event on select input

The option element is not designed to directly support click events.
<select class="selectpicker"  @change='prueba($event)'>
  <option data-content="<i class='fa fa-eye mr-5' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option1"></option>
</select>

